# High memory usage in ASP.net site

Tags: asp.net, memory-management

I am doing performance tuning for one of my asp.net mvc websites. I run the CLRProfiler to measure the memory usage. The finding is through the time, the biggest memory usage increase is caused by the function as showed in the pricture.  [image]. The finalizer used 27MB then after few clicks, it went up to 60MB.  I think this is an .net internal method. Can someone please help me to understand this and how to fix this. 
Cheers

Comment: Do you have a higher res image?  I can't make out the text in the screenshot.

Comment: Hi Philip, if you try to open the image in a new tab, you will see the high res image. cheers